# VB.Net IEnumerator(Of Integer, MyClass) not possible?

Tags: vb.net, class, typeof, enumerator, ienumerator

How do I return a `IEnumerator` of a `SortedDictionary(Of Integer, MyClass)`

I have this.

```
Dim dictionaryTest As New SortedDictionary(Of Integer, MyClass)
Dim enumerator As IEnumerator(Of Integer, MyClass) = dictionaryTest.GetEnumerator() '<- not possible.
```

I want a function like

```
public function getTestEnumerator() as IEnumerator(Of Integer, MyClass)
   return dictionaryTest.GetEnumerator()
end function
```

Error generated in IDE
`'System.Collections.IEnumerator' has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments.`

Comment: Have you imported the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace? Also I believe it is actually an `IEnumerator(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Myclass))`

Comment: That works perfectly it was `Of KeyValuePair(...)` what I was missing. Strange why I dont have to use `KeyValuePair` for `SortedDictionary` but I need it for `GetEnumerator()`.  I left it just `IEnumerator` also seems to work

Comment: Haven't imported the `System.Collections.Generic` still no compiler errors or warnings. Don't need that library I think, `Imports System.Collections` works but maybe I'm importing everything not sure

Comment: There are two `IEnumerable` interfaces - the generic `IEnumerable(Of T)` and the non-generic `IEnumerable`. IIRC the former is in `System.Collections.Generic` and the latter in `System.Collections`

Comment: As far as the `KeyValuePair` I'm not sure why you didn't need it in the top sample, VB must be doing something cute behind the scenes. I'm pretty sure the sample would *not* work in C#.

Comment: Oh thanks anyways might as well answer the question if you want., yeah trying to keep it as simple as possible thats why I stick to VB haha. I wouldn't of even used these Ennumerators but  the modification of the arrays while looping is why i'm forced too.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to answer the question yourself if you'd like. Besides, you found the solution. I just happened to have pointed you in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim dictionaryTest As New SortedDictionary(Of Integer, MyClass)
```

Answer is replace

```
Dim enumerator As IEnumerator(Of Integer, MyClass) = dictionaryTest.GetEnumerator() '<- not possible.
```

with

```
Dim enumerator As IEnumerator(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Myclass)) = dictionaryTest.GetEnumerator()
```